# Reload Linux service from Node.js application

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx

I have Nginx running on Debian in the cloud. Usually, after I update it's configuration files I manually run `sudo service nginx reload`. Now I write a service in Node that updates the files and should restart/reload Nginx afterwards.
I have tried a number of npm modules and now I'm using [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs).
Running `shell.exec("sudo service nginx reload")` I get exit code 1, because Node does not have access to sudo and with `shell.exec("service nginx reload")` I get exit code 127 "command not found".
What am I missing? How can I reload a linux service from inside Node.js application? Ideally, I'd like it to happen syncronously.

Comment: It is not a good practice to give any service root/sudo access. 
If you still need to do it, then check from which user you are running. If it is root, then you most likely don't have `service` in your path. Try running `which service` from regular user. It will show you full path to binary like `/sbin/service`. Also in most cases you can do `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`.
If it is not root, then you should add user sudo permissions with `visudo`. There is a lot of info in google about it's syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I added `ALL ALL = /etc/init.d/nginx` to the sudoers file. As I understand it just allows every user/process to access nginx commands?